# Particle system to create texture

Tags: rendering, particles, memory-management

I've made a forest scene with Botaniq add-on with lots of grass and trees which means lots of particles. Obviously slows everything down massively.

Is there a way to "freeze" layers or manage the layers so that I can add extra things.

For example I want to add a fire but I'm pretty sure the combination would actually set my computer on fire.

Basically, what is the best ways to deal with multiple particle systems?

Comment: If you mean slowdown in a Viewport you can disable ps from Viewport visibility or in object properties set Viewport visibility as Bounding box.

Answer (score 0):

Hi if by freeze layer you mean can you freeze the particles in their current place and stop them from further emitting, then yes.

You can select the particle system
under the modifier tab,
you have the option to convert the particles to a static mesh.

Comment: If user already noticed slowdown .... Converting particle system to real geometry will be killing ....

Comment: I'll try both of these thanks. I guess what I was really asking is what techniques are there to deal with massive  scenes? Could be particles, physics, animation or just sheer number of vertices that all add up to make working on a scene very laggy.